# validation of setter by constraint

Tags: oracle, jdbc, code-generation

Hello to all friends;

I am writing a **code generator**.
 Given the following Query to obtain information about the constraints.

```
SELECT 
     alc.search_condition as condition
FROM 
     all_cons_columns cols 
     LEFT JOIN all_constraints alc 
     ON alc.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
     AND alc.owner = cols.owner 
     LEFT JOIN all_constraints r_alc 
     ON alc.r_constraint_name = r_alc.constraint_name 
     AND alc.r_owner = r_alc.owner 
     LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns r_cols 
     ON r_alc.constraint_name = r_cols.constraint_name 
     AND r_alc.owner = r_cols.owner 
     AND cols.position = r_cols.position 
WHERE 
     alc.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
     AND alc.table_name = 'XXXXXXX'
     AND cols.column_name ='YYYYYYY'
     AND alc.constraint_type='C'
```

How can use for validation from the field "**condition**" in java code ?
 I want validated setter methods Given the value field "conditions".

Comment: Are you saying you want an automated process that takes the SQL condition of the constraint and creates Java code that validates input data according to this constraint? Sounds pretty involved...